# error using sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, html, firebug, local-storage

I am trying to use sessionStorage on a page but it is giving me an error.
Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
 sessionStorage.setItem("classname", "value1");
 sessionStorage.setItem("classdesc", "value2");
</script>
```

The error I get from firebug console is: Operation is not supported" code: "9

When I try to use localStorage it works fine, so why does sessionStorage cause an error?

Comment: Does using `window.sessionStorage` show the same problem?

Comment: Are you loading via file:///?  http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui3/ticket/2529165

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that "the page isn't ready", try placing this code at the **end of the body section**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <!-- YOUR PAGE HERE -->
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
      sessionStorage.setItem("classname", "value1");
      sessionStorage.setItem("classdesc", "value2");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Final Answer:**
sessionStorage wont work in "local mode", but it will work if you upload the file to a server.

Comment: I just figured out, *sessionStorage* wont work in "local mode", but it will work if you upload the file to a server.

Comment: You are correct, figured it out myself when I finally uploaded it to my server last night, Thanks!