# GWT Exception in Storage.isSupported()

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, gwt-2.4

I am struggling with a GWT problem that suddenly occurred in a component of my app that I didn't even touch.

I get an `Operation is not supported` exception in the 2nd line of [Storage.isSupported()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/storage/client/Storage.html#isSupported%28%29), a function of [GWT implementing the W3C's HTML5 storage specification](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html):

```
function Storage$StorageSupportDetector_0(){
    this.isLocalStorageSupported = typeof $wnd.localStorage != 'undefined';
    this.isSessionStorageSupported = typeof $wnd.sessionStorage != 'undefined';
}
```

This is really perplexing, because it's all GWT internal stuff. The above function is generated by GWT from GWT's own code. Plus: The problem occurs **only in production mode**. In development mode, everything works fine.

I am using plain GWT 2.4 (the latest) and no additional libraries. The problem is not browser-specific (I tried them all).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Please answer also if you don't know the concrete solution, but have a tip on how I could approach this problem in general.

Thanks!

Comment: You'd better write that as an answer to your question, rather than a comment; so that your question doesn't appear as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research, and carefully composing the above question, I found this:

[Error using sessionStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383494/error-using-sessionstorage)

In short, Session Storage does not work if you loaded the page from `file:`. Oh well.

(We might still want to keep this question around because it might enable people to find the solution by searching for the function code I posted.)

Comment: GWT should still be fixed to give a more meaningful error message imho. But well.